# ValueBinding issues in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I am facing issue in getting updated value in the view.  I think **valueBinding** is not working

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" >
            {{#view App.Test }}
                <label>Name:</label>
                {{view Ember.TextField  placeholder="username" valueBinding="view.name"}} </br>  </br>
              {{/view}}
      </script>

App.Test = Ember.View.extend({

    name: null,

     submit: function(event) {
       // event.preventDefault();
       console.log(this.get('name'));

    }

})
```

When submit function called, **console.log(this.get('name'));** allways shows NULL value, even though value is typed in the textfiled.

Comment: Could you please make in jsfiddle?

Comment: Try valueBinding="name" instead as you are already inside the view block helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already inside the  block helper you don't need to bind using "view.name" , 
But in cases where the application is intialized by router & the views are connected to the `outlets` you might need to use "view.name" to refer to the properties inside the view, For example
**Basic App Setup**

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create();

MyApp.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.create({
    index: Ember.Route.create({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'home',
      home: Ember.Route.create({
        route: '/home',
        connectOutlets: function(router){
          router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
        }
      })
    })
  })
});

MyApp.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
})

MyApp.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'home',
  name: 'TheName'
})

MyApp.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  name: "Joey"
})

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
 {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
  {{view.name}} I am from Home View
  {{name}} I am from the Home Controller
</script>
```

As you can see, in this case when you do `{{name}}` it looks for the property in controller & if you want to use the property from the view you need to use `{{view.name}}`
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GyHYg/1/)

Comment: Are you sue it is working! http://jsfiddle.net/GyHYg/ see this link, it is not working

Comment: That was pretty rough example I gave, I've edited your fiddle to make it work, we need to load ember & handlebar libraries in order for the code to work inside the Manage Resources panel, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/GyHYg/1/